# How can I align html grandchildren based off CSS Grid Lines?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to create a section using css grid split up into 3 areas, header (yellow), body (red) and controls (blue). Each of these areas will have its own div which are the grid items, and children elements within these divs.

[image: example]

Is there a way I can order the children within each div based on the grandparents css grid lines? e.g. have the 'tick' (row2/3 col3/4), which is in blue div line up with the 'input' (row2/3 col2/3), which is in the yellow div.

Comment: I think this is what grid exists to solve. You simply make the initial grid elements (yellow, red, and blue) grid containers themselves and layout their grids to be consistent across and down. Although you won't need as intricate a layout, the cells of your squared paper could be used to define the inner grids (e.g. your blue grid will contain it's own grid of 2 x 14 - the tick box aquare occupying cells 4,5,6 from the top, with the tick position over 5. The yellow grid would have 6 vertical cells, with your input field on cell 5 . ) etc.

Comment: Thanks @DavePritlove , so in this scenario the blue grid container would just use the same grid-template-row values as the parent container?

Comment: [You can use CSS Subgrid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIQa9f0REtM)

Comment: @ZachJensz Subgrid is awesome but unfortunately I need wider browser support.

Comment: @Finnegan Then I think you will have to change your markup to have all your areas share the same parent unfortunately

Comment: @Finnegan I suppose you could define the parent grid to a much higher resolution (e.g. 25 column cells and 14 column cells, and make the inner cell grids using the same units) but it's not really neccessary- the inner cells can all be independent grid containers with each constructed with its neigbours in mind. They don't care what grid they were placed into. Sorry if I'm confusing, I should post an example but it's a little late here. I'll check back tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any grid *item* can also be a grid *container*

My snippet includes an approximation to your sketch, defining an outer container with rows and columns defined as px and % values respectively, creating the grid line numbers equivalent to your sketch (i.e. 4 line / 3 cells across, and 4 lines / 3 cells down)

```
  grid-template-columns: 20% 70% 10%;
  grid-template-rows: 25px 25px 150px;
```

then, each `div` is positioned to the grid by referencing the lines. e.g. for the 'blue' field:

```
.blue {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
```

Note it now occupies the full height in the last 10% of the outer grid container.

Now, the blue field can also be a grid *container* with its grid defined with neighbouring cells in mind. Recall the row template used for the parent grid, was defined in pixel heights:

```
  grid-template-rows: 25px 25px 150px;
```

We can see the height ratio of these rows is 1:1:6 and can use this ratio to define the rows we wish to 'imagine' in the blue column. So, after the css rules for the `blue` class that define its place in the parent grid, we can define it to be a grid container, with its own inner cells - in this case one cell wide, three cells high, with the heights corresponding to fractions of the total height:

```
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 6fr;
```

In the html, the area you want to display your tick, is nested in a div inside the `.blue` div:

```
  <div class="blue">
     <div class="tick">√</div>
  </div>
```

and in the stylesheet, the position in the blue grid of the .tick div is defined:

```
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
```

lastly, to position the (text) tick inside the `.tick` div, we make it a flex box and make use of the align and justify properties (we could have made it a grid container again but that might get confusing):

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

By applying the same flex styling to the neighbouring yellow box, we can ensure the input field lines up nicely with the tick.

Ofcourse, you can change the heights of the rows in the outer container, provided you make the corresponding adjustments to the fractional heights for the blue container (if the ratio of pixel heights changes). You could also use pixel units throughout but I deliberately mixed px, % and fr to emphasise the independent nature of grid containers inside grid items (you almost have to 'forget' the item is in a grid and think of it as any other block on the page).

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 70% 10%;
  grid-template-rows: 25px 25px 150px;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  background: black;
}

.to {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background: yellow;
}

.from {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background: yellow;
}

.label {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background: yellow;
}

.input {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background: yellow;
  
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.red {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  /* these numbers refer to the grid lines defined in the .container grid */
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  background: blue;

  /*this grid cell can also be a grid *container* */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 6fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.tick {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  width: 80%;
  height: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="to">One</div>
  <div class="from">Two</div>
  <div class="label">Three</div>

  <div class="input">
    <input type="text"> 
  </div>

  <div class="red">Five</div>

  <div class="blue">
     <div class="tick">√</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Grid is really powerful, if sometimes a little tricky to choose the best definitions (it almost has too many ways to achieve similar results).